# Making identity providers in ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET CORE co-exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have migrated a ASP.NET MVC project to ASP.NET Core and currently testing it.

I would like to keep the current version and the new version using the same database during these testing and staging phases.

Both apps uses ASP.NET identity providers. When we have green light, we put the new app in production while the database is already in place.

To make the database work in ASP.NET Core, I had to do some changes, like adding new columns for some normalized values and add the AspNetRoleClaims table as well. After that .NET Core works fine, but the old application is failing authentication at login operation.

My desktop client applications are also failing to get the authentication bearer tokens. I read something that bearer tokens are no longer default in .NET Core 3.1.

Not sure how and if these two problems are related, but is there any changes I could make this work, so I could make a smooth transition?

Comment: Almost all bearer token questions in SO are about ASP.NET Core, not ASP.NET MVC. ASP.NET Core Identity is a far newer version than the one found in ASP.NET MVC so breaking changes aren't only guaranteed, they are expected and actually welcome - we do want new features in new major versions. If you want to use the same authentication service, use Identity Server and have both applications use it

Answer (score 0):

Your need:

> Making identity providers in ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET CORE co-exists.

It's worse practice. Because your mixed system is not unified, many errors. Let's try to migrate to ASP.NET Core with (ASP.NET Core Identity) totally.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Even I migrate to ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET Core Identity, then I would still require some steps to enable bearer token authentication.
Is there a practical way to configure this and do not add breaking changing to current mobile client applications? Bearer tokens are currently requested by the "/token" method...